# How to detect new versions of docker images when tags are mutable and does not reference base image version?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, dockerhub, docker-image

Postgres is just an example, I'm interested in the general case.

I use the official postgres docker image from docker hub. It seems to be tagged with postgres versions (postgres:11.8-alpine) which of course make sense, and I can spot new versions by looking at the available tags. So far, so good.

The official postgres image is based on alpine and when a new version of alpine is available new versions of the postgres image seems to also be made available, so I should be able to stay up to date on the base image also.

However, the tags seem to be treated as mutable, so the new image has the same tag as the old ("postgres:11.8-alpine"), and I can't tell that it's a new image (with up to date alpine) from looking at the tag.

Are image tags ment to be mutable? How can I find out if I need to upgrade? Do I need to keep track of image SHAs?

Comment: 1. Yes, tags can be mutable (see e.g. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/396736/110531 for a post I wrote from the provider's perspective). 2. Need to upgrade from what perspective? Find out if there are vulnerabilities, find out whenever the image changes, ...? 3. If you need to pin a specific image, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Docker tags can be mutable. Indeed in that case, you need to follow SHAs.

Personally, I use [RenovateBot](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) to update my deps and they have a post on that problem https://renovate.whitesourcesoftware.com/blog/overcoming-dockers-mutable-image-tags/